# Count each observation a row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, format

I have a pandas df named df, with millions of observations (rows) and only 4 columns.

I'm trying to convert the event_type column into several columns, and add a count to each row for that column.

My df looks like this:

```
    event_type            event_time       organization_id     user_id                 

0   Applied Saved View  2018-11-22 10:59:57.360    3            0
```

And I'm looking for this:

```
    Applied_Saved_View event_time              organization_id user_id
0       1              2018-11-22 10:59:57.360    3              0
```

Comment: you gotta give some sample data and little more details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something called pd.get_dummies. I assume you are trying to make this categorical data? I have no way of testing without sample data but see code below.

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['event_type'])
new_df = pd.concat([df2,df],axis=1)
```

I should mention, you should see how many unique values there are in this event type column because those each will become rows whether its 10 or 100000 unique values